# Coverage report with istanbul and mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, loopbackjs

I'm a newbie on Node.js. I have to set up some tests in my application and I'm getting really mad trying to generate a back-end code coverage report with `mocha` and `istanbul` in my `loopback` application.

Searching through thousand of dab explained articles on Github I found some good [articles](http://www.vapidspace.com/coding/2014/10/29/code-coverage-metrics-with-mocha-and-istanbul/) and then I figured out that I had to use something like this:

```
istanbul cover _mocha -- [path/to/test/files] -R spec
```

I was happy because it says: "What you are essentially doing is passing the command to run your tests to Istanbul which, in turn, will run those tests on your behalf." However, every time I try to run Istanbul, I get this error:

```
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
C:\...\proj-name\node_modules\.bin\_mocha:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My working test file is:

```
var userService = require('../TestBusinessLogic.js');
var should = require('chai').should();

describe('API Utenti', function() {
  it('should throw Exception on missing UserName', function() {
    (function() {
      userService({ Name: 'Pippo', Surname: 'Baudo' });
    }).should.Throw(Error);
  });
});
```

Is this command good to use? If not, could someone please explain me how to make a coverage report using `istanbul` with `mocha`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured that I was running `node_modules\.bin\_mocha` instead of `node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha` and this solved my problem.

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me - it complains:
```Unable to resolve file [./node_modules/bin/_mocha]```
Here is my package.json scripts config:
```"scripts": { "test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha test", "coverage":"./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/bin/_mocha -- test -R spec" }```

Answer (score 2):

When running `istanbul` from the command line you need to run it from the root of your project directory, it by default looks for the files to run the coverage reporting for at the root of your directory.

Additionally make sure your path to your test folder is relative to your project directory.

So you should navigate to your project directory using `cd` and then when inside your project directory then run

`istanbul cover _mocha -- ./path-to/test.js -R spec`